# Error: No response is returned from route handler in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I try to fetch the data from database using mysql in next.js using API routes functionality But when I call the route they show me the this error

> Blockquote Error: No response is returned from route handler

Here I can write code like below

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import db from '../../../../lib/db';

export function GET(request){
    db.query('SELECT * FROM department', (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error querying the database:', error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' },{status:500});
      }

      return NextResponse.json({ data: results },{status:201});
    });
}
```

When I call this api in console it show me the message Connected to MySQL database successfully and then after it show the above error

Comment: Which error? You didn't include the error message in your question.

Comment: Error: No response is returned from route handler This error show me in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it issue could be in a code. In your code db.query function work as async manner and before your db query complete they return response.
So you must used promises to solve the issue.

```js
try {
    const results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query('SELECT * FROM department', (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ data: results }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error}, { status: 500 });
  }
```